# How to get the benefit of INET framework in OMNET++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

How could I get the benefit of Inet framework on omnet++ to build a wireless communication system without editing the existed source codes? (use the existed source code as a black box)
for example, I want to receive a msg at node B from node A, and then reply to node A in a different time with a new msg and different details of the scenario using for example TCPGenericServiceApp.

Comment: your post belong to networking you can post it here https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think so, as this question directly addresses the usage of an OMNeT++ simulation framwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INET is a quite modular framework.
The OMNeT++ network is created using a `omnetpp.ini` file which is usually located in the according example folder.

If you now want to change something without changing the files included in INET you can try to create your own network.
Hence, you have to create your own `omnetpp.ini` in a new folder and than describe your network in that file.
Using this method, you can create your own network setup with network modules, already provided by INET.

If you also want to change the behavior of a certain `simple module` provided by INET you can create a new OMNeT++ project which is based on INET.
Then you can use all modules provided by INET as base classes.
To change their behavior, you have to create new subclasses from the INET base classes and override the according methods. Also you have to create new `NED` files for your new C++ classes.
Then you can use your newly defined network modules in your `omnetpp.ini` without the need of changing anything in the current INET repository.